# PHP Function to Display Textual Representation of Boolean Value

Tags: php, boolean

Is there a PHP function that shows a textual version of the boolean setting of "1" as "True" or "On", etc.?

I know how to use if() statements to make it happen, but I searched and could not find anything that might be a shortcut to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: i dont know if you would call it a shortcut, but json_encode() does exactly that. the function provided in Rawkode answer is faster and more clean, you should use that

Comment: You're right @BenM .. it was asked and answered before. Thanks for linking.

Comment: Unfortunately the accepted answer to that question is right, but not the "rightest" one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for var_export:

```
var_export(true, true) : string = "true"
```

If you have an integer value, you can use type juggling beforehand:

```
var_export((bool) 1, true)
: string = "true"
var_export((bool) 0, true)
: string = "false"
```

Please see the chapter on type juggling http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php before you attempt to run this with the Strings "On" and "Off" - the first one will evaluate to true, the latter one to - guess! (I'll help, it's true as well). So beware. An empty string however would be casted to false.

Comment: It was my understanding of the question that the author wanted a function to convert boolean values to text, such as True or On and not to determine a boolean value for the text itself.

Comment: Well, var_export does exactly that. As you can see the result is a string (which in my understanding is text). See the manual for var_export, especially the second "return" parameter:
"If used and set to TRUE, var_export() will return the variable representation instead of outputing it."

Answer (score 1):

```
function boolToText($bool) {
  return $bool ? 'True' : 'False';
}
```

Comment: Ok thank @Rawkode. It looks, behaves and requires as much code as an if() statement. But it looks good.

Comment: Same result as `return var_export((bool) $bool, true);`

Comment: But the output can't be altered, should they wish to return "On" or "Off". I don't believe it matters anyway, both ways will do as been asked.